# Best way to store data for reading from file + querying API?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Basically I want to:

1. Read names newline delimited from a file
2. Query an API for the names. There might be one or many responses tied to a name.
3. Storing the name and responses.

What makes sense is to create a list of dictionaries with a name key/value and a response key/value(s) - but I don't know how to do this.

If this seems like the "best" approach I'd love some tips on how to create the list of dictionaries - or if it's a terrible idea, then what would be the better alternative?

Comment: Using a dict could work, but only if you are sure the names are unique. 
What I would do though, is store the names in a list, then the responses in another list, but in the same order.

Comment: @NicolasPerez thx I might try that.